# Yii2 RBAC update only own posts permission

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app, rbac

I am  following [this guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) but I am unable to give permission to update own posts.
I have created AuthorRule.php

```
<?php

  namespace common\rbac;

  use yii\rbac\Rule;
  use backend\controllers\PostsController;


 class AuthorRule extends Rule
 {
public $name = 'isAuthor';

/**
 * @param string|int $user the user ID.
 * @param Item $item the role or permission that this rule is associated width.
 * @param array $params parameters passed to ManagerInterface::checkAccess().
 * @return bool a value indicating whether the rule permits the role or permission it is associated with.
 */
public function execute($user, $item, $params)
{
    return isset($params['model']) ? $params['model']->createdBy == $user : false;
     }
  }
```

and PostsController.php

```
use common\rbac\AuthorRule;

 public function actionUpdate($id)
  {
     if (\Yii::$app->user->can('updateOwnPost', ['model' => $model]))
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->post_id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
else
{
    throw new NotFoundHttpException('You have no access to update this post');
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to acces on my page "update action", I recive this error[image]

Comment: You are passing `$model` to `can()` but it's undefined at this stage. You set it later on. Put it in first line.

Comment: thanks a lot it helps